# JS equivalent of Python str() method

Tags: javascript, python

In Python 2.7.3, there is a method called `str()` which turns all data types into strings. I was wondering if there was a string method like this in JavaScript and if so, what the syntax was for it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: Unlike python, Javascript is loosely typed, so explicit type casts are rarely needed. You can do `"somestring" + 12345` without any conversions.

Answer (score 8):

[string function in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp)

```
<script>

var test1 = new Boolean(1);
var test2 = new Boolean(0);
var test3 = new Boolean(true);
var test4 = new Boolean(false);
var test5 = new Date();
var test6 = new String("999 888");
var test7 = 12345;

document.write(String(test1)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test2)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test3)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test4)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test5)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test6)+ "<br />");
document.write(String(test7)+ "<br />");

</script>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
true
false
true
false
Mon Oct 22 2012 16:30:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
999 888
12345
```

check this function too

```
var iNum1 = 10;
var fNum2 = 10.0;
var iNum = 10;

alert(iNum1.toString(2)); //outputs “1010”

alert(iNum1.toString(8)); //outputs “12”

alert(iNum1.toString(16)); //outputs “A”
```